# MySQL: Backup Remote Database

Tags: java, mysql

I am working with MySQL. I need to do *Remote Backup* of database.As of now , i am doing **ssh/scp** for this operation .Is there any other simplified way to achieve this, like a single command so that it can be used via Java Run Time lib.

Comment: You mean copying database backup to a remote server ? or taking backup from a remote server to locally ?

Comment: taking backup from a remote to local server

Comment: Try this solution. the mysql command is mysqldump, don't need ssh/scp

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954543/how-to-backup-mysql-db-from-remote-to-local-without-mysql-local-installation

Comment: I see there is a way without connecting to the server via ssh. You can use the host name in the mysqldump command as `mysqldump -u user -p -h hostname > file.sql`, but need to make sure that for this mysql user the database is accessible from outside. These parameters are defined in MYSQL  user table where you can see host is set to `localhost` if its changed to `%`. But its not good to have `%` since it could be accessed from any IP address. Rather better to specify an IP address which can access the remote data. Or create a new user by proving the ip address.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I am using only IP Address for hostname

Comment: yes then it should work the complete dump code would be `mysqldump -u user -p -h xx.xxx.xxx.xx dbname > file.sql` if the mysql in the given host is accessible from outside then the above command should work.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I am checking for Reachability of the remote host before doing backup.